# Pipeline in Sitecore active directory module?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've already installed the Sitecore active directory module. When a user from active directory has been created, deleted or renamed I want to execute some custom code. Is there a pipeline or function to hook in? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As Trayek said, you can add your custom event handlers in the events:

//Creation
`<event name="user:created">`
`</event>`

//Deletion
`<event name="user:deleted">`
`</event>`

//Updation
`<event name="user:updated"/>`
`</event>`

First of all, override the Sitecore's code, in your custom command and debug, maybe you will be able to fetch the selected roles also, where you can see if the user is an active directory is selected, then you do your custom action, else let it execute as it is.

Hope it helps!

Regards,
Varun Shringarpure

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the  standard `<event name="user:created" />`, `<event name="user:deleted" />` and/or `<event name="user:updated" />` events. You can find these in the web.config, under the `<events>` node.

I don't know if the module comes with it's own pipelines/events, otherwise it might be better to use them.

[edit]
Do keep in mind this will also run for the creation, deletion and editing of other users (extranet, Sitecore, other domains).